# How do I scale and offset an input to an ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, adc, ngspice

The background is: I want to monitor a 12 V lead-acid battery with an ESP8266.

The ADC has an input range of 0 to 1 V (or 0 to ~3.2 V if using a module i.e. WEMOS D1).

I am only interested in the battery voltages between 10 and 15 V to maximise the information in the 5 V input range over the 1 V ADC range.

I see lots of posts and tutorials on this topic but they limit themselves to a simple two resistor divider, but I think I need something like an op-amp (single voltage, rail-to-rail) with a Zener as a reference.

My electronics knowledge is not up to the task. Any advice on a suitable circuit will be most welcome.

[image: Graph showing input 0-15v (blue) and output 0-3.3v (red)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanded Scale ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22492/expanded-scale-adc)

Comment: also note that scaling will make only two thirds of your ADC range useless. And I *mean* "only", because I bet you have way more effective bits in your ADC than you actually need to make a good decision on battery state, *especially* since I bet that measurement's going to be noisy, so software filtering of the observed voltage is probably a good idea, and would get you the ~1.2 bit you lose in resolution if you just scale. **EDIT** ESP8266 has a 10 bit SAR ADC. The datasheet is a bit too silent on performance data of that for my taste, but let's assume 8 bit ENOB; pretty conservative bet.

Comment: So, your plain scaled 0 to 15 V range resolution would be (15-0)V/2⁸ = 59 mV. I *heavily* doubt you would really need more for a battery state estimation. What would you do that would require knowing the battery voltage is 11.75 V, not 11.72 V (ADC value 200 in 15/256 V), nor 11.78 V (ADC value 201 in 15/256 V)? How can you know the operating state (namely, temperature, current draw, age, charge history) to such a high degree of precision that you would need more than ca 6.8 bits to represent your range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to do a complete design, that's too much like real work to calculate error budgets and so on, and the specifications would need to be tighter. But here is the general idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGVQuT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You pick Rser and Rshut to give a division ratio puts the input voltage well within the input range of the op-amp. In this case, suppose you pick 100KΩ and 10KΩ so the division ratio \$a = 1/11\$.

Now we need to pick another arbitrary (more or less) value, so I'll pick \$ R_1 || R_2 || R_3 = 10{\rm\,k\Omega}\$.

Then we have (with a minimal amount of math and equating the input voltages of the op-amp, and eliminating R3 for now)

$$
R_1 = \frac {V_{out}(h) - V_{out}(l)}{V_{in}(h) - V_{in}(l)}\cdot \frac {1}{a} \cdot 10{\rm\,k\Omega}
$$

Substituting R1 into one of the two end points we have

$$
R_3 = \frac
  {V_{ref}}
  {V_{in}(l)\cdot a \cdot \frac{1}{10{\rm\,k\Omega}} - V_{out}(l) \cdot \frac {1}{R_1}}
$$

And then R2 is easily calculated from $$ \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{10{\rm\,k\Omega}} - \frac{1}{R_1} - \frac{1}{R_3}.$$

If you get negative resistance values you'll have to change the input divider value as the overall gain post-divider cannot be less than 1.

The Vref is called upon to sink as well as source current so if it is a shunt type it must have sufficient current to allow that to happen without it going out of regulation.

For a real design you have to consider input and output ranges of OA1, reference voltage and stability (note that the offsetting voltage is directly proportional to Vref so with a (say) 8V offset a 0.1% change in Vref represents 8mV delta at Vin). And op-amp offset voltage and bias currents.

Ideally you'd match \$ R_{ser}||R_{shunt} = R_1||R_2||R_3 \$ to reduce input bias current related offset, and you'd also like to use more-or-less standard values of resistors. Left to you to calculate.

Eg. using your numbers, and some likely sub-optimal choices of parts:

The green line is the output voltage vs. input. The blue line shows the reference current and that it remains well within the 10μA..2mA guaranteed operating range. In reality I'd probably use an LM4040 but the reference shown is in my model library.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the circuit. However, it seems? that there isn't an ADA4505 to be found anywhere? Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Digikey, Mouser, Arrow, Verical each have 5,000+ in stock. Two of them  have > 90,000 in stock each.

Comment: Okay. I guess it must be a UK issue?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to take a battery with a possible voltage of 0 to 15 V, only worry about the top 5 volts of that, and scale it to 0 - 3.2 V. So you need to subtract 10 V to get 0 - 5 V, and then divide by 1.562 to get 0 -3.2 V.

Here's a circuit that does the subtraction and then uses a voltage divider. I added some filtering to it, not sure if it needs it, or maybe it needs more. It works in simulation but may need some tweaking. It's powered from the battery itself, you could change that if you have a better voltage source.

I've run the simulation with the battery voltage from 0 to 15 V, only from 10 to 15 produces an output voltage.

[image: scaler divider]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day you need an op-amp if you need to really high impedance, the op amp is used as an impedance buffer to present a high impedance to the load and a low impedance source to the ADC.

I would think that most batteries would have low enough source impedance that a resistor divider should be sufficient. I would think that with going from a 12 volt source down to a 3-volt in most applications a resistor divider could be used.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple design could look like this, where V2 is the battery being monitored:

[image]

The buffer minimizes current draw from the battery and sources the current for the voltage divider. Using a zener diode with a 10 V breakdown clips any lower voltages, turning your 10- 15V range into roughly 0 - 5V. Then the voltage divider reduces this into a 0 - 1V range. The zener voltage and effective resistance depends on the current through it, so the resistor values should be chosen to yield Vz as close to 10 V as possible while also providing the correct 5:1 voltage division. You can see in this rough simulation that 15 V at the battery results in 0.995 V at the ADC.

One drawback here is that the response of this circuit won't be perfectly linear due to the fact that Vz changes as a function of Iz. This could be mitigated by calibration or ignored depending on  your spec.

Comment: I like "simple"! 
Can you offer a part number (3v3 supply & rail-to-rail output) for the op-amp?
And is there a problem with the input exceeding Vdd?

Comment: I included the buffer here to minimize the amount of current drawn from the battery by the monitor. It would need to be powered with Vdd > 15 V to avoid saturation, but it could be omitted to reduce cost. If so, then you would probably want to increase the resistances to reduce current draw from the battery. This would have the effect of decreasing Vz slightly, closer to 9.5 V for the 1N4740.